# Dynamically update circle size in ImageView using SeekBar - Android

Tags: android

in my app I have dialog with seekbar which sets size to my painting brush and below this I wanted to make simple preview of this size. I managed to create ImageView just below this seekbar and draw a circle inside. As long as I make progress bigger than it was previously everything works fine, circle is dynamically growing like it was supposed to, but when I lower progress nothing happens. I guess that everytime I change progress' value new circle is appearing on the old one, so when I want to make circle smaller it can't be seen. I've tried methods like `setImageBitmap(null)` or `setImageResource(0)` but it didn't worked. 
My code looks like this:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.brush_size,null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setView(view)
                    .setTitle("Change brush size");
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            final Bitmap preview = Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(preview);
            final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(mPaintView.getColor());
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            sb.setMax(50);
            sb.setProgress(mPaintView.getSize());
            sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    mPaintView.setSize(progress);
                    canvas.drawCircle(50,50,mPaintView.getSize(),paint);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(preview);
                }
```

Is there any way to actually clear my imageView everytime I change the progress bar, so smaller circles can be visable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawing this with **`Color.TRANSPARENT`** and **`PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`** parameters should do the trick.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    mPaintView.setSize(progress);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
    canvas.drawCircle(50,50,mPaintView.getSize(),paint);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(preview);
}
```